# Is SaveChanges() Necessary with Function Imports (Stored Procedures)?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

Is ***SaveChanges()*** necessary with function imports (stored procedures)?

Example:

```
void foo(Product product)
{
    // AddProduct is a function import of a stored procedure
    entities.AddProduct(product.Name, product.Price, product.Description);

    entities.SaveChanges(); // Is this necessary?
}
```

Comment: have you tried it? :)

Comment: I have. It doesn't seem to make a difference either way. The underlying stored procedure is called. Maybe I should've rephrased and asked, 'SHOULD I call SaveChanges()?' -It isn't clear to me due to lack of documentation, if I should or shouldn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx), `SaveChanges`

> Persists all updates to the data source and resets change tracking in
>   the object context.

That is, for any entities that are attached to the context and which you have added, modified or deleted, EF will generate the corresponding SQL code and run it against the database. In your case you are already running SQL code (more or less) directly against the database by calling the `AddProduct` stored procedure. So in your case `SaveChanges` won't do anything and is not necessary (unless you have other unsaved changes on the ObjectContext of course).