# Does the execution of a stored procedure in Entity Framework 6 need a call to SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have question about calling stored procedures in Entity Framework. I have this code:

```
using (var context = new DbContext("test"))
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SomeStoredProcedure");
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Do I need to call method `SaveChanges` directly (like in this example) or will this transaction be committed automatically?

Comment: Have you tried it? Execute it without the `SaveChanges()` and see if it persists.

Comment: This question is very similar to, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726913/is-savechanges-necessary-with-function-imports-stored-procedures

Comment: I've tried and this transaction commited, and my question is: is there any solution to prevent commiting stored procedure unless I directly call method SaveChanges?

Comment: If you have a new question you need to open a new one.

Comment: What does this sproc do? I have a feeling that EF isn't really being used in this case (maybe switch to Dapper?) or that this sproc could be replaced by a database trigger.

Answer (score 5):

`SaveChanges` basically synchronizes changes in the context's change tracker with the data store. When you call a stored procedure by `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` the context itself it totally oblivious of any changes the stored procedure may have applied to the database, so `SaveChanges` won't commit any of these. They *are already committed* (assuming that the stored procedure modifies data).

Your underlying question seems to be how to commit all changes (from the sproc and from SaveChanges) in one transaction. If that's what you want, you can wrap your code in a [`TransactionScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using (var ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    using (var context = new DbContext("test"))
    {
        ... // more code here
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SomeStoredProcedure");
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    ts.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `SaveChanges()` command is not necessary after the `ExecuteSqlCommand()` call.
However, note that the context will not know about the changes that occur during that call until the entities are reloaded.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Starting with EF6 `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` by default will wrap the command in a transaction if one was not already present. There are overloads of this method that allow you to override this behavior if you wish. Also in EF6 execution of stored procedures included in the model through APIs such as `ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction()` does the same (except that the default behavior cannot at the moment be overridden).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx